# Error with derived class using overloaded operator from base class

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I'll post my issue and then I'll have the code at the bottom.

I have a base class (strSet) that has overloaded +,-,*,= operators.
I have a derived class (extStrSet) that has overloaded <,>,== operators

In the implementation of the overloaded '<' and '>' operators in the derived class, i have to use the '*' operator (from the base class).

**But I am getting an error that I'm really not sure why is happening. The errors say this:**

```
extstrset3.cpp: In member function âextStrSet extStrSet::operator>(const extStrSet&)â:  

extstrset3.cpp:17: error: no match for âoperator=â in âtemp = strSet::operator*(const strSet&)(((const strSet&)(&((const extStrSet*)rtSide)->extStrSet::<anonymous>)))â  

extstrset3.h:11: note: candidates are: extStrSet& extStrSet::operator=(const extStrSet&)
extstrset3.cpp: In member function âextStrSet extStrSet::operator<(const extStrSet&)â:  

extstrset3.cpp:29: error: no match for âoperator=â in âtemp = strSet::operator*(const strSet&)(((const strSet&)(&((const extStrSet*)rtSide)->extStrSet::<anonymous>)))â  

extstrset3.h:11: note: candidates are: extStrSet& extStrSet::operator=(const extStrSet&)  

extstrset3.cpp:35: error: ânewSetâ was not declared in this scope  

extstrset3.cpp: In member function âextStrSet extStrSet::operator==(const extStrSet&)â:  

extstrset3.cpp:41: error: no match for âoperator=â in âtemp = strSet::operator*(const strSet&)(((const strSet&)(&((const extStrSet*)rtSide)->extStrSet::<anonymous>)))â  

extstrset3.h:11: note: candidates are: extStrSet& extStrSet::operator=(const extStrSet&)  

extstrset3.cpp:45: error: ânewSetâ was not declared in this scope
```

**NOTE:** I am not to change either of the two header files.
**NOTE:** I know for a fact that strSet.h and strSet.cpp are implemented correctly.
**NOTE:** The overloaded '==' operator returns a extStrSet (string set) with "true" or "false" as its only string

I should be able to use the * operator on extStrSet even though its overloaded for strSet, shouldn't I? I'm just starting inheritance so I'm still a bit wary of it.

**strSet.h**

```
#ifndef STRSET_H
#define STRSET_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct node {
    std::string s1;
    node * next;
};

class strSet {

protected:
    node * first;
        // This is initially empty (when constructed)
    bool isSorted () const;

public:
    strSet ();  // Create empty set
    strSet (std::string s); // Create singleton set
    strSet (const strSet &copy); // Copy constructor
    ~strSet (); // Destructor

    void nullify (); // Make a set be empty
    bool isNull () const;
    int SIZE() const;

    void output() const;

    bool isMember (std::string s) const;

    strSet  operator +  (const strSet& rtSide);  // Union
    strSet  operator *  (const strSet& rtSide);  // Intersection
    strSet  operator -  (const strSet& rtSide);  // Set subtraction
    strSet& operator =  (const strSet& rtSide);  // Assignment


};  // End of strSet class

#endif
```

**extStrSet.h**

```
#ifndef EXTSTRSET_H
#define EXTSTRSET_H

#include <string>
#include "strset3.h"

class extStrSet : public strSet
{
public:
    extStrSet operator == (const extStrSet& rtSide);  // Equal
    extStrSet operator <  (const extStrSet& rtSide);  // Strict subset
    extStrSet operator >  (const extStrSet& rtSide);  // Strict superset
    // Leave off other comparisons: != <= >=

    extStrSet ( );
    extStrSet (std::string s);
};

inline extStrSet& ss2extss (const strSet& ss)  // Downcast
   { return *(extStrSet*)&ss ; }

#endif
```

**extStrSet.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "extstrset3.h"
#include "strset3.h"

using namespace std;

extStrSet::extStrSet() : strSet() {}

extStrSet::extStrSet(string s) : strSet(s) {}

extStrSet extStrSet::operator >  (const extStrSet& rtSide) {
    extStrSet temp;
    extStrSet temp2;
    extStrSet newSet;
    temp = *this * rtSide;
    temp2 = *this == rtSide;
    if(temp2.isMember("true")) extStrSet newSet("false");
    else if( rtSide.SIZE() == temp.SIZE() ) extStrSet newSet("true");
    else extStrSet newSet("false");
    return newSet;
}

extStrSet extStrSet::operator <  (const extStrSet& rtSide) {
    extStrSet temp;
    extStrSet temp2;
    temp = *this * rtSide;
    temp2 = *this == rtSide;
    if(temp2.isMember("true")) extStrSet newSet("false");
    else if( SIZE() == temp.SIZE() ) extStrSet newSet("true");
    else extStrSet newSet("false");
    return newSet;

}

extStrSet extStrSet::operator ==  (const extStrSet& rtSide) {
    extStrSet temp;
    temp = *this * rtSide;
    if( SIZE() == rtSide.SIZE() && SIZE() == temp.SIZE() ) extStrSet newSet("true");
    else    extStrSet newSet("false");
    return newSet;
}
```

Comment: Does it help to do temp = this->operator*(rtSide);

Comment: Nope, I tried that and received the same errors.

Comment: Could it be that operator* needs to return strSet& or const strSet&?

Comment: It does. The * operator takes two string set (strSet), and returns a string set (strSet) that is the union of the two.

Comment: No, I meant that sometimes the presence or absence of const gives rise to these errors. Also, do you think you could try implementing operator< for strSet? This will tell you if the problem is with inheritance or something else. Besides, are you sure operator= for the base class includes all functionality for the derived classes?

Comment: The only data in the strSet is a linked node list. extStrSet doesn't add any new data, just adds three comparison operators ==,<, and >. So the '=' should cover everything for the derived class as well. The rtSide is treated as const in the '=' operator. I tried returning it as a const but that didn't change anything.

Comment: It seems the problem is with the any operator from the base class (strSet). Because the = operator works for temp2 = *this == rtSide. And it also works for a basic thing like this temp = rtSide. Any ideas? Like, I know the base class operator are implemented correctly, as I used them when I was just using the strSet class (without inheritence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the strSet::operator*() returns a strSet not an extStrSet.  To be clear this expression

```
*this * rtSide;
```

returns a strSet.  This part

```
extStrSet temp =
```

expects to be given an extStrSet, but it is given a strSet.  You have this function

```
inline extStrSet& ss2extss (const strSet& ss)  // Downcast
{ return *(extStrSet*)&ss ; }
```

For converting from strSet to extStrSet. I believe that in this case you can do

```
temp = ss2extss(*this * rtSide);
```

but it is important to note that this only works, because there are no virtual functions in these classes and extStrSet does not add any data members.  The difficulty is because the * operator is defined as

```
strSet operator*(strSet &rhs)
```

That is return by value not by reference.  That means that even if that function has a return statement that returns an extStrSet, the extStrSet part of it will be truncated.  In this case because of the lack of virtual functions and data members I believe this will work on just about any compiler, but even with all that I am not 100% confident that this does not rely on undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Fact: the extStrSet only adds a couple of operators; it doesn't add any or change the actual underlying set.

By implication I think you should, in the implementation of the extStrSet operators, only use instances of the baseclass. operator==() is only defined for extStrSet so you can leave that one as-is, since inside operator>() you're sure that both 'this' and 'rtSide' are (at least) instances of extStrSet.

HTH,
h.

```
extStrSet extStrSet::operator >  (const extStrSet& rtSide) {
    strSet    temp;
    extStrSet temp2;
    // explicitly call baseclass operator*
    temp  = (this->strSet::operator*)(rtSide);
    temp2 = (*this == rtSide);
    if(temp2.isMember("true"))
        return extStrSet("false");
   else if( rtSide.SIZE() == temp.SIZE() )
        return extStrSet("true");
   else
        return extStrSet("false");
}
```